# Migrate sonatype Nexus data from a VM to pod which is running in kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, redhat, nexus, sonatype

Previously we were using nexus which is running in a VM now we want move to kubernetes cluster. I deployed nexus in a kubernetes cluster and it is running fine. now i want to transfer complete data i.e., repositories, packages to a pod which has `/nexus-data/` folder.

from a VM a imported all the data from data directory and stored it in my local system. Bu when im trying to copy from local system to nexus pod im getting

`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "tar": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

when i tried to install tar using microdnf i'm getting an error

`error: failed to obtain lock 'metadata': Failed to create file ?/var/cache/yum/lock/dnf-metadata.lock.XXXXXX?: Permission denied`

how can i install tar so that i can copy folders from my local system to nexus pod.

Comment: Which container image are you using?

Comment: @GariSingh I'm using `sonatype/nexus3:3.47.1` container image. Installed it using `nexus-repository-manager` helm chart